# OLEDE Error: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\ComputerName$'.;28000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc, ssas, oledb

I am trying to deploy an Analysis Services cube in SQL Server 2012. My user account is `REALM\Merin`  where `REALM` is the domain and my computer's name is `Hercules`. I am already in Analysis Service's administrator group. When I process the cube using SQL Server Data Tools, I get following error.

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error. Login failed for user
>   'REALM\Hercules$'.; 28000.

My user account is REALM\Merin but I don't know why it is complaining about user REALM\Hercules$. What does this account mean? A user with ComputerName + $ is strange to me. Someone help please.

Thanks,
Merin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I did not understand about the ComputerName$, but I was able to resolve my Cube deployment error.
Below are the steps:

1. Double click the data source in the Analysis Project Click
2. Impersonation Information tab
3. Select Use a specific Windows user name and password
4. Enter user name and password and click OK
5. Process the Cube

:)

Comment: its working on my analysis project, I follow same steps

Comment: I was actually looking for such solution from the Visual Studio side with a BI project. It is pretty much similar solution except you'd choose "view Designer" on right-click of the project

Answer (score 5):

Get your Windows Username and Password from SSMS and use it in the impersonation info area as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Look into the "Impersonation Information" tab of you data source object in the cube. You probably selected "Use the service account", and this is `REALM\Hercules$`. And probably the account under which the Analysis Services service is running does not have access rights to the relational data source. Configure the impersonation in a way that the access is allowed, and processing should work.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue:

> OLEDE Error: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\ComputerName$'.;28000

The fix in my situation was to:

1. Change the Analysis Service account  from the default to a domain account
2. Grant the domain account read access to the data source

Answer (score 2):

1. Run 'Sql Server Configuration Manager' and check 'Log On As' account name of SQL Server Analysis Services (...name...).
2. Copy this account name (double click to open and then copy)
3. Open 'SQL Server Management Studio' and login to 'Database Engine'.
4. Go to Security > Logins click on 'New Login...' and give the copied name.
5. Restart

Should be able to deploy now.

Answer (score 1):

Below Steps Solve Cube Processing Error.

(For Visual Studio 2015 Data Tools/Business Intelligence Studio) 
Double Click Data Source to open Data Source Designer -> Impersonation Information (TAB) -> 1st Option: Enter Credentials-> Click OK

(For SQL SERVER Management Studio 2016) 
Double Click Data Source to open Data Source Properties -> Under Security Settings, Click Impersonation Info (dropdown) -> 1st Option: Enter Credentials -> Click OK.